# Error loading MacroEngine script (file: )

Tags: asp.net, macros, umbraco

So i have an issue suddenly with several macros stopped working.so i run the ?umbDebugShowTrace=true in the URL to see a few issues all the macros have the same issue.

```
Error Loading Razor Script (file: All Office Locations Map (Widget)) 

'umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeList' does not contain a definition for 'Any'    at 

CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )

at ASP._Page_macroScripts_Widgets_Widget_AllOfficeLocationsMap_cshtml.Execute() in c:\sites

\teeslaw.igentics.com\macroScripts\Widgets\Widget_AllOfficeLocationsMap.cshtml:line 6

at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()

at System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter 

writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
at umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorMacroEngine.ExecuteRazor(MacroModel macro, INode currentPage)
at umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorMacroEngine.Execute(MacroModel macro, INode currentPage)   

0.858238407395353   0.013762
```

umbracoMacro    Loading IMacroEngine script [done]

```
Error loading MacroEngine script (file: /Widgets/Widget_AllOfficeLocationsMap.cshtml, Type: ''
'umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeList' does not contain a definition for 'Any'
at umbraco.macro.renderMacro(Hashtable pageElements, Int32 pageId)
```

I am a newbie to umbraco so any help would be appretiated please be as clear as you can Version number is umbraco v 4.11.5

Comment: Sometimes a simple app pool restart solves the problems. MacroScripts are a bit flakey.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error crop up when a dll in the bin folder is missing a dependency. It's hard to troubleshoot since the error given on the macro scripts is completely unrelated. Have you recently installed/uninstalled any new packages or performed any upgrades?

One way I've been able to track down the true error is the run some other code on the site that isn't macro related. Typically that code will not run and instead will throw the correct error.

Comment: i deleted the bin folder today and used a previous working backup but still the error is there ?

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed this problem is by removing some DLL files that had conflicts.

- WebGrease.dll
- TweetSharp.dll
- BundleTransformer.sass.scss.dll

Hope that helps anyone else who gets this problem